# Server error in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am using FRED API to convert natural language into *RDF/XML* format data.

While running as a normal Python file it is executing correctly but when I use it in *Django* framework views.py file it is showing *Server error (500)* , My *views.py* file is as below:

```
import urllib2
import urllib 
import httplib2
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext

def cur(request):
    par = {"text": "wanted android developer with 3 years experience"}
    headers={"Accept" : "application/rdf+xml"}
    request = urllib2.Request(
        "http://wit.istc.cnr.it/stlab-tools/fred/?" + urllib.urlencode(par),
        headers=headers)
    contents = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
    graph = urllib2.urlopen(request).geturl()
    repository = 'good_boy'
    params = { 'context': '<' + graph + '>' }
    endpoint = "http://localhost:3030/openrdf-sesame/repositories/%s/statements?%s" % (
        repository, urllib.urlencode(params))
    (res, cont) = httplib2.Http().request(endpoint, 'PUT', body=contents, headers={ 'content-type': 'application/rdf+xml' })
    context_instance = RequestContext(request)
    return HttpResponse(content)
```

Comment: The code is not indented properly

Comment: Please, turn on DEBUG mode in settings.py to know exactly which row of code  cause error. And format your code, it seems like wrong number of indents.

Comment: `content` variable is not initialized. see `return HttpResponse(content)`

Comment: return `HttpResponse(cont)`